# python heapsort implementation

Tags: python, list, heapsort

I am trying to implement heapsort algorithm in Python. 
I get the error: list index out of range, although this part of the code should not be executed if the index is out of range.

```
def swaper(child,parent,a):

    temp = a[parent]
    a[parent]=a[child]
    a[child]=temp


def digswap(swap,a):

    '''
    swap here is the position of the former child, which was just swapped with 
    its parent. The concept is to check if the node that now contains the parent value
    has childs. If it has, then we might have to restore the heap property.
    '''

    if (2*swap)<=len(a):
            if a[2*swap]>a[swap]:
                    swaper(2*swap, swap, a)
                    digswap(2*swap,a)
    if (2*swap+1)<=len(a):
            if a[2*swap+1]>a[swap]:
                    swaper(2*swap+1, swap, a)
                    digswap(2*swap+1,a)
```

I get the "list index out of range value" for "if a[2*swap]>a[swap]". I don't understand why, since this part should not be executed if 2*swap > lean(a).

Comment: What if `2*swap == len(a)`?

Answer (score 3):

Lists are 0-indexed. If `2*swap == len(a)`, then the last valid index in `a` is `2*swap - 1`, hence your error.

As an aside, you don't need the `swapper` function; you can simply write `a[parent], a[child] = a[child], a[parent]`. It's much more efficient and is a common Python idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexing starts at 0. This leads you to access one past the last element of the array.

say you have `a = [1,2,3,4]` then `len(a)` is 4. The last element of this array is `a[3]`. This means that from the line:

```
    if (2*swap)<=len(a):
```

you can get a value of up to 2 for swap which means that you essentially are doing:

```
a[swap*2]
a[4]
```

which is one past the end of the array.